# List(of Int32).Contains([int64 value]) doesn't work because of disimilar types

Tags: vb.net, list, contains, ilist

I have a list of integers that have been deserialized by WCF from json. This list deserializes as a list(of int32). I don't have any control over how it deserializes.

I need to be able to see if this list contains a value that happens to be an Int64. It obviousy doesn't work. Here is a sample of the function:

```
Private Shared Function IsIn(aPropertyValue As Int64, aList As IList) As Boolean
    Return aList.Contains(aPropertyValue)
End Function
```

The reason I'm passing IList is because I don't want to have to create this function 12 times, once for each numeric type, byte through uint64. If I did create it 12 times, acutally 12 x 12 times for every possible option, I guess I could use List(of T).Exists().

The documentation for Contains() says it uses IEquatable(Of T).Equals to perform the comparison. I have to think that an Int32 and an Int64 with the same value can be compared and be found to be equal.

I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: From documentation for `IEquatable<T>.Equals`: "The implementation of the Equals method is intended to perform a test for equality with another object of type T, the same type as the current object. ". So, no, it is not supposed to be able to compare values of different types. In any case, if the list was deserialized as `IList<int32>`, then your 64-bit value has already been either truncated or wrapped-around. If you want to work with it, you need to ensure that it does deserialize correctly.

Comment: Why are you creating a function with one line of code?  Just use the one line of code.  Problem solved.

Comment: assuming you know that your 64-bit value is in the range of 32 bits (else, throw exception?), can't you just do a Convert.ToInt32() on it? -- i.e., Return aList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(aPropertyValue))

Comment: one line of code is because we are creating Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)).

Comment: kmote, we can't guarantee the generic type of the list because sometimes WCF serializes the list funny so that GetGenerics returns nothing even though the list is clearly of a certain type.

Comment: kmote, we also do not want to convert the int64 to an int32 as this would not be safe within the context of the system. the int64 is an int64 because it needs to be. the int32 list isn't an int64 list because WCF seems to have no way to specify the type of an array of numbers.

Comment: GetGenericArguments not GetGenerics.. it's getting late...

Comment: Would it be feasible to convert the values in your list to Int64s?

Comment: Timiz, at least in theory that would work. The above function is just one of twelve we've defined for the IN operation. The system we've designed allows us to create query predicates in JavaScript that can be used in the web client, or passed to the server (JSON) where they are converted to LINQ predicates which can be used to query in memory data or a databae (LINQ2Sql). We support most common comparison operators. Everything else in the system is tested and works perfectly. Only trying to build the IN clause for in memory queries doesn't work. I hoped to avoid writing 144 IN functions.

Comment: it is what it is. i've written the functions and the project goes on. thanks for the comments - they were definately helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Function IsIn(ByVal aPropertyValue As Long, ByVal list As IList) As Boolean
    Dim genericListType As Type = CType(list, Object).GetType().GetGenericArguments()(0)
    Dim convertedPropertyValue As Object = Nothing
    Try
        convertedPropertyValue = Convert.ChangeType(aPropertyValue, genericListType)
    Catch
    End Try
    If convertedPropertyValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Return list.Contains(convertedPropertyValue)
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```